# Select large amount of data from SQL server over high latency network

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, query-performance

I need to query about 40000 rows from SQL Server 2012 SP1 over network with high latency (ping is about 39ms).

When I run that query from SSMS on remote machine, it takes about 1 sec to load everything.

However, executing same query on same machine with `SqlDataReader` takes about 19.1 seconds (in synchronous version of reading profiler tells that ~92% of time consumed by SNI).

When `Packet Size=32768` (max possible value) parameter set, `SqlDataReader` load everything in 3.6 sec (~59% consumed by SNI).

However it is still 4 times longer compared to SSMS. And in both cases without SNI it looks pretty close to what I get in SSMS.

If I run same code querying data with `SqlDataReader` directly on SQL server machine, it takes about 0.9 sec to load everything. However I need to run this code on remote machine. And I need to load data directly from SQL server as I cannot place another application there. All rows are about 3mb - several small string and integer columns.

Obviously, ping is the problem.

How does SSMS load all rows so fast even with high latency?

How can I achieve same behavior? Maybe somehow without ADO.NET?

Query is simple `SELECT`, it executes fast and return about 40000 rows (I do need them all for further processing that cannot be done on SQL Server).

Timing measured with simple code, like this:

```cs
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        count++; // simple counter to ensure same number of rows was read
}
```

Comment: I believe SSMS is written in optimized C++, which minimizes overhead.  You could try that.

Comment: @user1443098 Most of time spent on data exchange over network. How does SSMS downplay the influence of high latency? Looks like, it's not about C++ vs C#, but about implementation details of SNI or TDS.

Comment: Well...when you execute the query on the server it doesn't have to push any data over the network. Once you query it remotely the result set gets pushed over the network. Not sure why that would be confusing. I would argue that 3MB per row is not "several small string and integer columns". That is not a small amount of data to push over a slow network connection.

Comment: @SeanLange I execute exactly the same query on the same database in SSMS and in my app on the same machine. SSMS get all data in ~1 sec, and app in ~4 sec. It's 4 times longer and I see no way to get even close to SSMS's timing.

Comment: As you stated you have figured out why, it is your network. You are pulling quite a bit of data over a pipe you stated you know is not fast. Maybe look at the execution plans and see if they are different. Is this a stored procedure with parameters? Maybe you are getting parameter sniffing issues?

Comment: @SeanLange exactly same queries, exactly same plans and costs, exactly same results for both, SSMS and my app. Both interact over TCP/IP, not pipes.

Comment: OK. Where is SSMS running? On the server or a remote machine?

Comment: @SeanLange Both, app and SSMS running on remote machine. App executed in ~4 sec, SSMS in ~1 sec. Same remote machine, same query, same plan, same result. I run app on server once just for comparison that without network latency it could work fast - it executed in ~1 sec too.

Comment: SQL Server secretly recognizes that it is being called from SSMS and boosts peformance for those queries?